# How to ensure the template type is scalar in D?

Tags: templates, d, scalar

I have two functions: one is scalar multiplication for a vector and other - vector-matrix multiplication:

```
pure T[] mul(S, T)(S s, T[] a)
```

and

```
pure T[] mul(T)(T[] a, T[][] B)
```

Of course this leads to a conflict, as `S` can be a vector too, so that first template covers the second. How do I tell compiler, I want only scalar type to be `S`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a [template constraint](http://dlang.org/concepts.html).

```
pure T[] mul(S, T)(S s, T[] a) if (isScalarType!S)
```

This declares that the template should only be considered when `isScalarType!S` is `true`.

[`isScalarType`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#.isScalarType) can be found in [`std.traits`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html).

In D, the scalar types are the numeric types, character types, and `bool`. You can restrict further using the other traits from `std.traits` if you like (e.g. `isNumeric` or `isFloatingPoint`).